# Standard interface for the C language for generating syslog messages

Tags: c, syslog

Which way is standard to generate IETF-syslog messages in the C language?

There is the header <syslog.h>. But it provide no options to use the STRUCTURED-DATA mechanism ([rfc-5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424)).

Of course, messages could be constructed by hand directly to a socket. But it seems that such way is not standard.

Is there another standard way?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... [that RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424) is less than 2 years old. I don't think it is a big surprise to see that the ususal suspects haven't implemented it yet.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is to have your application log messages using the normal `openlog()`, `syslog()` and `closelog()` routines from `<syslog.h>`.

That will send the messages to the `syslogd` running on the local machine.  If the messages are then to be forwarded over the network using the syslog protocol, `syslogd` itself will take care of this.  For example, this might be done using a target like `@hostname` in the `syslogd.conf` file.

In short, your application is expected to log messages to the `syslogd`, and `syslogd` decides where to send them (including over the network).  This allows the local administrator maximum control.